# How to get document-topics using models.hdpmodel – Hierarchical Dirichlet Process in gensim

Tags: document, gensim, cpu-word, lda, hdp

I just study gensim for topic modeling. when I use

```
lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(...)
```

the result lda_model has two functions: get_topics() and get_document_topics(). I can find the topic-word and document-topics by them. But, I want to try:

```
hdp_lda_model = gensim.models.hdpmodel.HdpModel(...)
```

I can only find there is get_topics() in its result, no something like get_document_topics(). So I cannot find the relation of document and topics. But it should be somewhere. I read some instruction from https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/hdpmodel.html. But I did not find any (maybe I miss something?). So is there a function in hdp model, which is like get_document_topics() in lda model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both models have a `__getitem__` method that does what you want.

For LDA it's actually a wrapper of `get_document_topics`
https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/ldamodel.py#L1503

And for HDP it's wrapping the `inference` method but doing additionally more than just calling it:
https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/hdpmodel.py#L427

So, to answer your question. You can do for both models:

```
lda_model[bow_doc]
```

or

```
hdp_lda_model[bow_doc]
```

and then get a topic distribution for `bow_doc`

Results in something like:

```
[(5, 0.05342164806543596),
 (7, 0.04307238446604077),
 (11, 0.5281130394662548),
 (31, 0.28899472194287035),
 (60, 0.07985460856925444)]
```